# Downloading and automatically installing a tgz file

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /tmp
curl -O http://www.mucommander.com/download/nightly/mucommander-current.app.tar.gz /tmp/mucommander.tgz
tar -xvzf /tmp/mucommander.tgz */mucommander.app/*
cp -r /tmp/mucommander.app /Applications
rm -r /tmp
```

I'm trying to create a shell script to download and extract muCommander to my applications directory on a Mac.

I tried cd into the tmp dir, but then the script stops when I do that.
I can extract all using the  -C argument, but  the current tgz path is muCommander-0_9_0/mucommander.app, which could change on later builds, so I'm trying to keep it generic.

Can anyone give me pointers where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Strip the first path component when you untar the archive, from tar(1):

```
 --strip-components count
         (x mode only) Remove the specified number of leading path ele-
         ments.  Pathnames with fewer elements will be silently skipped.
         Note that the pathname is edited after checking inclusion/exclu-
         sion patterns but before security checks.
```

#### Update

Here is a working `bash` example of how to, fairly generically, copy the contents of the `tgz` file to `/Applications`.

```
shopt -s nocaseglob

TMPDIR=/tmp
APP=mucommander
TMPAPPDIR=$TMPDIR/$APP

mkdir -p $TMPAPPDIR

curl -o $TMPDIR/$APP.tgz http://www.mucommander.com/download/nightly/mucommander-current.app.tar.gz
tar --strip-components=1 -xvzf $APP.tgz -C $TMPAPPDIR
mv $TMPAPPDIR/${APP}* /Applications
# rm -rf $TMPAPPDIR $TMPDIR/$APP
```

The `rm` command is commented out for now, verify that it does no harm before you use it.

Comment: He'll still need to modify his script, but this is an excellent way to make the script simpler.

Comment: I tried the following: #!/bin/bash

mkdir /tmp/mucommander
curl -o /tmp/mucommander/mucommander.tgz http://www.mucommander.com/download/nightly/mucommander-current.app.tar.gz
tar -xvzf /tmp/mucommander/mucommander.tgz --strip=1 muCommander-0_9_0/muCommander.app
tar -xvzf /tmp/mucommander/mucommander.tgz 
It extracts OK, but to my local directory. How do I get it to extract to /tmp/mucommander/muCommander.app?  I tried using -C, but it seems to ignore it

Comment: OK almost there, This seems to work:   tar -xvzf /tmp/mucommander/mucommander.tgz -C /tmp/mucommander --strip=1 muCommander-0_9_0/muCommander.app
   So my final question is, is it possible to replace muCommander-0_9_0 with a wildcard so I don't have to change the script if the path gets updated to say muCommander-0_9_1?

Comment: Thanks Thor, I made a couple of changes to your script since it was looking at the wrong path. I changed the following lines   curl -o $TMPAPPDIR/$APP.tgz http://www.mucommander.com/download/nightly/mucommander-current.app.tar.gz
tar --strip-components=1 -xvzf $TMPAPPDIR/$APP.tgz -C $TMPAPPDIR

Comment: Scratch the above, it timed out on me. It should read:  Thanks Thor, I made a change to your script since it was looking at the wrong path and could not find the tgz file. I changed the following line
tar --strip-components=1 -xvzf $TMPDIR/$APP.tgz -C $TMPAPPDIR     It now works correctly provided mucommander does not already exist in the  Applications folder, so I will either have to use rsync, or delete the program from Applications first with an if then else.  Thanks again for all your help. This is definately a good learning experience.

Comment: Final working script:                                          #!/bin/sh

shopt -s nocaseglob

TMPDIR=/tmp
APP=mucommander
TMPAPPDIR=$TMPDIR/$APP

mkdir -p $TMPAPPDIR

curl -o $TMPDIR/$APP.tgz http://www.mucommander.com/download/nightly/mucommander-current.app.tar.gz
tar --strip-components=1 -xvzf $TMPDIR/$APP.tgz -C $TMPAPPDIR
if [ ! -d /Applications/muCommander.app ]; then
 mv $TMPAPPDIR/${APP}* /Applications
else
rm -R /Applications/muCommander.app  
mv $TMPAPPDIR/${APP}* /Applications
rm -rf $TMPAPPDIR $TMPDIR/$APP $TMPDIR/$APP.tgz
fi

Answer (score 1):

The following will update your muCommander.

```
#for the safety, remove old temporary extraction from the /tmp
rm -rf /tmp/muCommander.app

#kill the running mucommander - you dont want replace the runnung app
ps -ef | grep ' /Applications/muCommander.app/' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill

#download, extract, remove old, move new, open
#each command run only when the previous ended with success
curl http://www.mucommander.com/download/nightly/mucommander-current.app.tar.gz  |\
 tar -xzf - -C /tmp --strip-components=1 '*/muCommander.app' && \
 rm -rf /Applications/muCommander.app && \
 mv /tmp/muCommander.app /Applications && \
 open /Applications/muCommander.app
```

*Beware, after the '\' must following new line, and not any spaces...*